# overriding certificate verification in windows8

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-8

I am trying to use a self-signed certificate in a ssl socket on windows8 consumer preview. I am getting this exception:

> Exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800B0109): A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800B0109 .

Is it possible to override the validation of ssl certificate ? Something like [remotecertificatevalidationcallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) , which does not seem to be accessible on windows8.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Add yourself to the trusted CA list. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/View-or-manage-your-certificates

Comment: I do not want to add manually. I would like to programmatically override it because the client and the server trust each other and just want to encrypt the data with server's public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Silverlight (which has a very similar security model), there is no way to go around a SSL error in a connection. The only workaround in my case was a server side proxy hiding the SSL errors.

I doubt that you'll find a way to do insecure connections in Win8's sandbox (same as in Silverlight).

Comment: We were able to get SSL to work with a real geotrust certificate. One good thing to note was that if you get a certificate for "foo.com" but your server's DNS does not end in "foo.com", you will have to Use the UpgradeToSslAsync

Comment: await aTcpClient.ConnectAsync(
                                new    Windows.Networking.HostName(Params.RemoteHost),
                                "443",
                                SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket
                                );

    // SEnd/Receive if you need to before starting ssl
    await aTcpClient.UpgradeToSslAsync(SocketProtectionLevel.Ssl, new Windows.Networking.HostName("x.foo.com"));